# How to stop at a specific number using loops

Tags: c, new-operator

So I'm trying to code something that when entered an integer will stop at a certain place.

That is n % 7 == 1;

for example, I'm I input 5, and I want it to stop at n % 7 == 1;
(User inputs 5 stops till 8 which is n % 7 == 1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
int nDay, I , nStop;
scanf("%d", &nDay);
nStop = nDay % 7 ==1;
if(nStop != 1)
{
for (i=nDay; i == nDay % 7 == 1; i++)
{
printf("%d", nDay);
}
return 0;
```

The problem is it is only printed once, is there a way to code this using loops only?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int num, i = 5;
// printf("Enter the number:\n");
// scanf("%d", &num);
 num = 5;

 while(i % 7 != 1){
    printf("%d\n", i);
    i++;
 }

 return 0;
```

}

If you feel and problem in understanding the code than just visualize the code using this website http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit